# Socket.io program won't work on website

Tags: javascript, sockets, socket.io

I need help getting a simple socket.io application to run on a website. I followed the tutorial from [here](https://socket.io/get-started/chat/) to get a simple chat application up and running. It works when I run it on my computer and connect through the local host but I can't get it to work when I try to put it on a webserver. I am using free hosting from [000webhostapp](https://www.000webhost.com/) so idk if that has something to do with it. My js code and html is:

index.js

```
 var app = require('express')();
 var http = require('http').Server(app);
 var io = require('socket.io')(http);

 app.get('/', function(req, res){
 res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
 });

 io.on('connection', function(socket){
 socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
 io.emit('chat message', msg);
 });
 });

http.listen(3000, function(){
console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Socket.IO chat</title>
            <style>
               * { margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }
                 body { font: 13px Helvetica, Arial; }
                 form { background: #000; padding: 3px; position: fixed; 
                 bottom: 0; width: 
                 100%; }
                 form input { border: 0; padding: 10px; width: 90%; margin-
                 right: .5%; }
                 form button { width: 9%; background: rgb(130, 224, 255); 
                 border: none; 
                 padding: 10px; }
                 #messages { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
                 #messages li { padding: 5px 10px; }
                 #messages li:nth-child(odd) { background: #eee; }
            </style>
    </head>
<body>

    <ul id="messages"></ul>
<form action="">
  <input id="m" autocomplete="off" /><button>Send</button>
</form>

<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>

<script>
     $(function () {
     var socket = io();
     $('form').submit(function(){
     socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val());
     $('#m').val('');
     return false;
    });

    socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
    $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(msg));
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What I'm about to say can be completely wrong, but when I worked websockets with PHP, I had to run the websocket in a command window. I think socket has to be an active process running and those shared hosting services usually don't allow you to run a command. Maybe your server is simply not running the socket code.

Comment: You need to actually run your web socket server process, which your host isn't doing.